# limiting variance and asymptotic variance of the inverse sample mean

Tags: variance, inference, asymptotics

In Casella's [Statistical Inference]，page 470. The definitions of

`limiting variance`: For an estimator $T_n,$ if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} k_nVar T_n = \sigma^2 < \infty,$ $\{k_n\}$ is a sequence of constants, then $\sigma^2$ is called the limiting variance.

`asymptotic variance`: For an estimator $T_n,$ suppose that $k_n(T_n - \tau(\theta)) \rightarrow n(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution. The parameter $\sigma^2$ is called the asymptotic variance of $T_n.$

1. Is there any restriction on $k_n,$ otherwise we choose $k_n = 1/(n^k)$ for very large $k,$ the limitation can easily converge to $0?$
2. Suppose $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ i.i.d with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2,$ for the inverse sample mean $1/\bar{X_n},$ we already known

$$Var\dfrac{1}{X_n}  \rightarrow \infty;$$
$$\sqrt{n}(\dfrac{1}{X_n} - \dfrac{1}{\mu}) \longrightarrow n(0,(\dfrac{1}{\mu^2}\sigma)^2).$$
Then what's the `limiting variance` of $1/\bar{X_n}?$ And is it already the example of `limiting variance` $\neq$ `asymptotic variance`? Since the author gave an additional example later.

Comment: I can't help thinking Casella must be making additional assumptions about $(k_n),$ because neither definition is workable.  After all, any $(k_n)$ that satisfies either condition will also satisfy that condition when multiplied by any constant, but the resulting $\sigma^2$ also is multiplied by that constant, making it completely undefined.

Comment: is there any conclusion that if $v(\theta)$ is the asymptotic variance of $T_n$ i.e. $T_n - \mu \rightarrow n(0,v(\theta))$ by distribution, then $\hat{Var}$ is the consistent estimator of $v(\theta),$ then $\hat{Var}$ is also the consistent estimator of $Var_{\theta} T_n?$

Comment: Are these common terms to describe variance asymptotics? I have not seen them in other texts.